# How can I unfocus an Entry in a NET MAUI application, particularly on iOS, when the user clicks outside the entry or anywhere else on the screen?

Tags: ios, maui

While in entry focus, I cannot unfocus by clicking anywhere on the screenthe only way to unfocus entry is click return button on keyboard.  How can I unfocus an Entry in a NET MAUI application, particularly on iOS, when the user clicks outside the entry or anywhere else on the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `HideSoftInputOnTapped="True"` on your `ContentPage`.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             HideSoftInputOnTapped="True"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
    <Entry />
</ContentPage>
```